# O que significa que meu código faz "comparações contra strings"?

Tags: javascript

O exercicio pede o seguinte:

Defina a função *Hipster* que recebe como parâmetro: a profissão de uma pessoa (string), nacionalidade (string) e o número de quilômetros que ele anda por dia (número). Com esses parâmetros avalie se essa pessoa é ou não (true / false), um Hipster. Tenha em mente que um Hipster é um Músico, nascido no Brasil e que gosta de andar mais de 2 quilômetros por dia.

Aí meu código:

```js
function Hipster(profissao,nacionalidade,kms){
  return profissao==="Músico" &&
    nacionalidade==="Brasil" &&
    kms>2;
  
}
```

Mesmo aceitando como válido, a plataforma SEMPRE retorna com a mensagem que o código "faz comparações contra strings" como se fosse algo errado e eu não sei o que isso quer dizer.

Comment: Algo que só o contexto pode indicar bem, e talvez só quem escreveu isso pode dizer o que é, provavelmente um termo errado e um local ruim para aprender, até por ser um termo ambíguo. Esses dias deu uma enxurrada de perguntas ruins partindo de algum site ruim que tenta ajudar as pessoas aprenderem JS, isso não vai dar certo. Eu poderia chutar algumas coisas, mas chute não ajuda muito.

Comment: Pelo jeito está pipocando de plataforma online de "boas práticas" (o que é péssimo). Digo isso por uma série de perguntas desse tipo que anda aparecendo no site. Depois o pessoal não sabe a razão de programador com base técnica ser uma raça quase extinta. Capaz da tal da plataforma não gostar de _magic numbers_ ou _magic strings_, mas sem contexto ou link com explicação adequada, a mensagem em si é inútil. Eu só daria um "desconto" caso a plataforma deste teste específico aqui tenha apresentado uma aula sobre isso e seja falha de quem fez o exercício não ter visto uma exigência de enunciado.